# Assistance writting function to list for api query in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple application to generate a 64char hex, translate to a private address and then check the balance via Etherscan. It works without issue. the API also allows checking addresses in groups of 20, separated by commas. I know i need to write the output of accAddress 20x to a list, i just don't understand how. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
import os
from ethereum import utils
import time
import urllib.request
import json
import secrets


hex_number = secrets.token_hex(32)
rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(hex_number)
accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)

url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=" + accAddress + "&tag=latest&apikey=YOURAPIKEY"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print (hex_number + "\n" + accAddress + ": " + data['result'])
```

Comment: Assuming you have stored `accAddress` values in a list(e.g. `acc_lst`), you can do `url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=" +'%2C'.join(acc_lst)+...`

Answer (score 0):

after much help, this is what works for me.

```
import os
from ethereum import utils
import time
import urllib.request
import json
import secrets

# Initialize main variables 
addressCount = 20 # Address number by request
allAddress = []
allHexNumber = {}

for i in range(addressCount):
    # Generate random eth address
    hex_number = secrets.token_hex(32)
    rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(hex_number)
    accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)

# Add address to list with its hex number
allAddress.append(accAddress)
allHexNumber[accAddress] = hex_number

# Join all the addresses by a ","
allAddressStr = ",".join(allAddress)

# Make the request
url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balancemultiaddress=" + allAddressStr + "&tag=latest&apikey=YOURAPIKEY"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

# Get and display the result for each balance with its hex number
allResults = data['result']

for result in allResults:
    address = result['account']
    hex_number = allHexNumber[address]
    balance = result['balance']
    print(hex_number + "\n" + address + ": " + balance)
```